# Swift: How to target a tagged UITextView in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITextField` on a `UITableView` that I need to target in a callback from a picker few delegate.  In Objective-C, this works well:

```
UITextField *myField = (UITextField *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:4];
```

When I try the following in Swift, I get a compiler error `Could not find member 'viewWithTag'`

```
let myField: UITextField = self.tableView.viewWithTag(4)
```

Xcode presents `self.tableView.viewWithTag` as an autocomplete option so I am surprised by this error.  Is this a bug?  If not, how can I target a tagged text field in Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After re-reading the [Swift manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_443), I can downcast on the right side of the assignment:

```
let myField = self.tableView.viewWithTag(4) as UITextField
```

This is now working as expected.

Comment: This is too helpful in near future